# Show that $\lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{2^{2m}m!(m+1)!}{(2m+1)!(2m+1)}=0$

Tags: limits, book-recommendation, infinite-product

After a long way to solve the differential equation $y''+xy'+3y=0$, I arrived at the solution $$y(x) = A_0 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^m \dfrac{2m+1}{2^mm!}x^{2m}+A_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^m \dfrac{2^m(m+1)!}{(2m+1)!}x^{2m+1}$$ and now I need to prove that it is convergent for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as the book claims.

Applying The Ratio Test, I will need just to show that the two following limits hold:  $$\lim_{m \to \infty} \dfrac{2^{2m}m!(m+1)!}{(2m+1)!(2m+1)}=0 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \lim_{m \to \infty} \dfrac{(2m+1)!(2m+3)!}{2^{2m+1}[(m+1)!]^2}=0. $$ But after lots of effort I don't know how to prove that the limits are zero and unfortunately I know not much about infinite products as all Real Analysis books teach only infinite sums! So my questions are:

1. Proving the mentioned limits.
2. A self-learn-able book containing lots of theorems and information about infinite products.

--

**Added.** [after reading @adfriedman's answer]: I have made a mistake regarding the second limit and the correct one is to show that $ \lim_{m \to \infty} \dfrac{(2m+1)!(2m+3)}{2^{2m+1}[(m+1)!]^2}=0$ which holds since $$\dfrac{(2m+1)!(2m+3)}{2^{2m+1}[(m+1)!]^2} = \dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{2m+3}k}{(2m+2)2^{2m+1}\prod_{k=1}^{m+1}k^2} =\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{2m+3}k}{(m+1) \prod_{k=1}^{m+1}(2k)^2} = \dfrac{2m+3}{m+1} \dfrac{1 \times 3 \times  \dots \times (2m+1)}{2 \times 4 \times  \dots \times (2m+2)} \ge \dfrac{2m+3}{m+1} \dfrac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{2m+1}(1+1/k)} \to 0$$

Comment: did you try with Stirling's formula?

Comment: @user108128, I don't know about Stirling's formula. (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html)?

Comment: $$n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n^n}{e^n}\right)$$ as $n\to \infty$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: @user108128, I tried Stirling's formula and it looks $\sqrt{n/8}$ after all replacings but it approaches infinity

Comment: It looks like you computed the ratios of consecutive terms in the two series incorrectly.

Comment: @BarryCipra, two series sums to one series and I tried $\lim |a_{n+1}/a_n|$ once for n odd and again for n even so why there is two limits

Comment: @Edi, I can see why you have two limits. What I'm saying is that you did not compute the ratio correctly for either series, so the limits you're asking about are not pertinent to the question of convergence of the series.

Comment: @BarryCipra, can you please help me with that? I took limits of $a_{2n+1}/a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+2}/a_{2n+1}$ in that case I made a mistake on putting ! in (2m+3) o.w. I don't know..

Comment: @Edi, ah, I finally see what you're doing: You are, in effect, combining the two powers series in the expression for $y(x)$ into one, and then applying the ratio test to that one power series.  I would suggest simply showing that each power series separately converges for all $x$. (I mistakenly thought that was what you were doing, and thought you had computed the ratios incorrectly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{2^{2m}m!(m+1)!}{(2m+1)!(2m+1)}
%
&= \frac{\left(2^{m}\right)^2 \left(\prod_{k=1}^m k\right)^2(m+1)}{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{2m+1} k\right)(2m+1)}
%
= \frac{\left(\prod_{k=1}^m (2k)\right)^2(m+1)}{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{m} (2k)(2k+1)\right)(2m+1)}\\
&= \frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^m \frac{(2k)(2k+1)}{(2k)^2}}\frac{m+1}{2m+1}
= \frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^m \left(1+\frac{1}{2k}\right)}\frac{m+1}{2m+1}
\end{align}

Since you wanted to learn some infinite product stuff (as opposed to just using Sterling's formula), from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) we have
$$1+\sum_{n=1}^N p_n \leq \prod_{n=1}^N(1+p_n)\leq\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^Np_n\right)$$

Applying this to the denominator product above, we can bound:

$$\frac{1}{\exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{2k}\right)}\frac{m+1}{2m+1}
\leq \frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^m \left(1+\frac{1}{2k}\right)}\frac{m+1}{2m+1}
\leq \frac{1}{1 +\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{2k}}\frac{m+1}{2m+1}$$

Clearly $\frac{m+1}{2m+1} \to \frac{1}{2}$, and we know $H_m=\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{k} \to \infty$ as it is partial sums of the Harmonic series, hence
$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{\exp\big(\frac12 \underbrace{H_m}_{\to\infty}\big)}}_{\to 0}\underbrace{\frac{m+1}{2m+1}}_{\to \frac12}
\leq \frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^m \left(1+\frac{1}{2k}\right)}\frac{m+1}{2m+1}
\leq \underbrace{\frac{1}{1 +\frac12 \underbrace{H_m}_{\to\infty}}}_{\to 0}\underbrace{\frac{m+1}{2m+1}}_{\to \frac12}$$

the left and right sides of the inequality approach $0$ and it follows that
$$\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{2^{2m}m!(m+1)!}{(2m+1)!(2m+1)} = 0$$
by the squeeze theorem.

Unfortunately this invalidates your second claim, note that
\begin{align}
\frac{(2m+1)!(2m+3)!}{2^{2m+1}[(m+1)!]^2}
&= \left[\frac{2^{2m+1}[(m+1)!]^2}{(2m+1)!(2m+3)!}\right]^{-1}\\
&= \left[\frac{2(m+1)(2m+1)}{(2m+3)!}\frac{2^{2m}m!(m+1)!}{(2m+1)!(2m+1)}\right]^{-1}\\
&= \bigg[\frac{2(m+1)(2m+1)}{(2m+1)!(2m+2)(2m+3)}\frac{2^{2m}m!(m+1)!}{(2m+1)!(2m+1)} \bigg]^{-1}\\
&= \bigg[\underbrace{\frac{1}{(2m+1)!}}_{\to 0}\underbrace{\frac{2m+1}{2m+3}}_{\to 1}\underbrace{\frac{2^{2m}m!(m+1)!}{(2m+1)!(2m+1)}}_{\to 0} \bigg]^{-1}
\end{align}
where I've intentionally refactored in terms of the limit that we already determined. Note that denominator goes to $0$ and strictly positive, hence the expression goes to $+\infty$, so:
$$\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{(2m+1)!(2m+3)!}{2^{2m+1}[(m+1)!]^2} = \infty$$
If you made a mistake when you derived that expression then you should now have the skills to prove the hypothetically correct expression.

As far as books go, I'd recommend Knopp's [Theory and Application of Infinite Series](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486661652). It has a pretty decent chapter showing how you can apply infinite series techniques to infinite products.

**Added**
In response to your edit, you have actually only shown the lower bound. Indeed, all terms are non-zero, so $0$ is a trivial lower bound anyway.

We first derive a simple upperbound on $H_m$:
$$
H_m
= \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k}
= 1 + \sum_{k=2}^m \frac{1}{k} \underbrace{\int_{k-1}^k \;dx}_{=\;1}
\leq 1 + \sum_{k=2}^m \int_{k-1}^k \frac{dx}{x}
=1+\int_1^m\frac{dx}{x}
= 1 + \log(m)
$$
hence
\begin{align}
0
&\leq \frac{(2m+1)!(2m+3)}{2^{2m+1}(m+1)!^2}
= \frac{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{2m+1}k\right) (2m+3)}{2\cdot (2^m)^2 \left(\prod_{k=1}^m k\right)^2(m+1)^2}\\
&= \frac{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{m}(2k)(2k+1)\right) (2m+3)}{2\cdot \left(\prod_{k=1}^m(2k)\right)^2(m+1)^2}
= \prod_{k=1}^m \left(1+\frac{1}{2k}\right) \cdot \frac{2m+3}{2(m+1)^2}\\
&\leq \exp(\tfrac12 H_m) \frac{2m+3}{2(m+1)^2}\\
&\leq \exp(\tfrac12 (1+\log(m))) \frac{2m+3}{2(m+1)^2}
= \frac{\sqrt{em}(2m+3)}{(m+1)^2}
\to 0
\end{align}

Comment: I edited OP. I had made a mistake and the second limit is zero. I would appreciate it if you please let me know if I did them right?

Comment: It looks like you only considered a lowerbound. I've provided details for an upperbound

Answer (score 2):

$y(x) = A_0 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^m \dfrac{2m+1}{2^mm!}x^{2m}+A_1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^m \dfrac{2^m(m+1)!}{(2m+1)!}x^{2m+1}
$

Use the root test
and Stirling
($n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n$).

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{2^m(m+1)!}{(2m+1)!}
&=\dfrac{m+1}{2m+1}\dfrac{2^mm!}{(2m)!}\\
&\approx\dfrac12\dfrac{2^m\sqrt{2\pi m}(m/e)^m}{\sqrt{4\pi m}(2m/e)^{2m}}\\
&=\dfrac12\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}\left(\dfrac{2m/e}{4m^2/e^2}\right)^m\\
&=\dfrac1{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\dfrac{e}{2m}\right)^m\\
\text{so}\\
\left(\dfrac{2^m(m+1)!}{(2m+1)!}\right)^{1/m}
&\approx\dfrac1{(2\sqrt{2})^{1/m}}\left(\dfrac{e}{2m}\right)\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$

For the first one:

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{2m+1}{2^mm!}
&=(2m+1)\dfrac{1}{2^mm!}\\
&\approx(2m+1)\dfrac{1}{2^m\sqrt{2\pi m}(m/e)^m}\\
&=\dfrac{2m+1}{\sqrt{2\pi m}}\dfrac{1}{2^m(m/e)^m}\\
&=\dfrac{2m+1}{\sqrt{2\pi m}}\left(\dfrac{e}{2m}\right)^m\\
\text{so}\\
\left(\dfrac{2m+1}{2^mm!}\right)^{1/m}
&\approx\left(\dfrac{2m+1}{\sqrt{2\pi m}}\right)^{1/m}\left(\dfrac{e}{2m}\right)\\
&\to 0
\qquad\text{since } m^{1/m} \to 1\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: 1. I don't know (theorems?) about consequences when limit of $(a_m)^{1/m} \to 0$ and 2. I don't see its connection to the ratio of two consecutive terms esp they are different (odd and even terms are not same formula).

Comment: This is the root test, not the ratio test. Look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Let's attempt to expand the factorials in the first limit and hopefully cancel some terms. Hopefully, then a similar approach will help on the second limit.

$$\lim_\limits{m \to \infty} \frac{2^{2m}m!(m+1)!}{(2m+1)!(2m+1)} = \lim_\limits{m \to \infty} \frac{2^{2m}(1\cdot2\cdots m)(1\cdot2\cdots m \cdot (m+1))}{(1 \cdot 2 \cdot 2m)(2m+1)^2}.$$

Since we are multiplying the numerator by $2$ $2m$ times, we can distribute the $2^{2m}$ as follows:

$$\lim_\limits{m \to \infty} \frac{(2\cdot4\cdots 2m)(2\cdot4\cdots 2m) (m+1)}{(1 \cdot 2 \cdot 2m)(2m+1)^2} = \lim_\limits{m \to \infty} \frac{(2\cdot4\cdots 2m) (m+1)}{(1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2m - 1))(2m+1)^2}$$
$$= \lim_\limits{m \to \infty} \frac{(2\cdot4\cdots 2m) (m+1)}{(3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2m + 1))(2m+1)} = \lim_\limits{m \to \infty} \left( \prod_{1 \leq i \leq m} \frac{2i}{2i+1} \right) \frac{m + 1}{2m + 1}$$
$$= \lim_\limits{m \to \infty} \prod_{1 \leq i \leq m} \frac{2i}{2i+1} \lim_\limits{m \to \infty} \frac{m + 1}{2m + 1}.$$

As you pointed out, $\lim_{m \to \infty} (m + 1)/(2m + 1) = 1/2$, so we'll have to show instead that $\lim_\limits{m \to \infty} \prod_{1 \leq i \leq m} \frac{2i}{2i+1} = 0$ and then we'll be done. A [theorem from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) says that an infinite product $\prod_{1 \leq i \leq \infty} a_n$ converges to a **nonzero** real number if and only if the sum $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq \infty} \log(a_n)$ converges. So, let's try to show that the sum $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq \infty} \log(a_n) = \sum_{1 \leq i \leq \infty} \log((2i)/(2i + 1))$ diverges, and then we can conclude that the infinite product, and the original limit, are $0$.

One approach could be the limit comparison test. This test only works on positive series, so we'll test the convergence of
$$-\sum_{1 \leq i \leq \infty} \log((2i)/(2i + 1)) = \sum_{1 \leq i \leq \infty} \log((2i + 1)/(2i)) = \sum_{1 \leq i \leq \infty} b_n.$$
The convergence of the negative form of a series implies the convergence of the positive form, and likewise for divergence.

Try comparing this sum with the harmonic series, the sum of $1/i$:
$$\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \frac{b_m}{1/m} = \frac{1}{\ln 10} \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \frac{\ln((2m + 1)/(2m))}{1/m} = \frac{1}{\ln 10}\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \frac{\frac{2m}{2m + 1} \cdot \frac{2m(2) - (2m + 1)2}{(2m)^2}}{-1/m^2} \text{ (L'Hospitals)} = \frac{1}{\ln 10}\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} -m^2 \frac{2m}{2m + 1} \cdot \frac{4m - (4m + 2)}{(2m)^2} = \frac{1}{\ln 10}\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \frac{-2m}{2m + 1} \cdot \frac{-2}{4} = \frac{1}{2\ln 10}\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \frac{2m}{2m + 1} = \frac{1}{2\ln 10} > 0.$$
Since the above limit is positive and nonzero, $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq \infty} b_n$ has the same convergence as the divergent harmonic series $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq \infty} (1/i)$. So $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq \infty} b_n = \sum_{1 \leq i \leq \infty} \log(a_n)$ is divergent, and from the theorem from Wikipedia above, then $\prod_{1 \leq i \leq \infty} = 0$.

As far as the second question about a book, I'm not sure as I haven't read any particularly outstanding books on the topic. But the methods I used here are taught from calculus 2. Consequently, this is a more basic approach; other approaches might use higher-level math.

Comment: Isn't $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \frac{m + 1}{2m + 1} = 1/2$?

Comment: Oh shoot, fixing my answer soon. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

With Stirling's formula approximation
$$n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n^n}{e^n}\right)$$ as $n\to \infty$
for the first one
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \dfrac{2^{2m}m!(m+1)!}{(2m+1)!(2m+1)}=\lim_{m \to \infty}\sqrt{\dfrac{2\pi \ m(m+1)^3}{(2m+1)^5}}\to0$$

Comment: I don't know how you go from $(n+1)[n(n+1)]^{n+1/2}/(2n+1)^{2n+3/2}$ to $n^{1/2}(n+1)^{3/2}/(2n+1)^{5/2}$.

Comment: try again ......

Comment: I forgot to say $\lim_\infty(1+\dfrac1n)^n=e$ and also $\lim_\infty(1+\dfrac{1}{2n})^{2n}=e$.

Comment: I got to $\sqrt{2 \pi e}n^{2n+2}/(2n+1)^{2n+3/2}$..

Comment: if you got that so tend to $0$ and you've done!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go beyond and even be able to approximate the value, consider $$A_m=\frac{2^{2m}\,m!\,(m+1)!}{(2m+1)!\,(2m+1)}$$
Take logarithms
$$\log(A_m)=2m \log(2)+\log(m!)+\log((m+1)!)-\log((2m+1)!)-\log(2m+1)$$ Use Stirling approximation
$$\log(p!)=p (\log (p)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log
   \left({p}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{12 p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ Apply it to each fcatorial and continue with Taylor expansion for large values of $m$. You should arrive to
$$\log(A_m)=-\frac{1}{2} \log \left({m}\right)+\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi
   }}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{8 m}-\frac{1}{4 m^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^3}\right)$$ Continuing with Taylor series
$$A_m=e^{\log(A_m)}=\frac 14 \sqrt{\frac \pi m}\left(1+\frac{1}{8 m}-\frac{31}{128 m^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^3}\right)\right)$$

For $m=10$, the exact value is $\frac{262144}{1851759}\approx 0.141565$ while the above approximation would give $\frac{12929}{51200}\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{10}}\approx 0.141537$